# Least Squares using QR for underdetermined system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to understand the usage of $QR$ decomposition for Least Squares problem of 
$$ Ax=b$$ 
when the system is underdetermined - $A$ is $m\times n$ and m < n, but $A$ is full rank and the system is stable.

Reading the following Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Advantages_and_disadvantages) on QR factorization, the section "Using for solution to linear inverse problems" isn't clear to me.
My logic for the solution was based on the following:
$$ Ax = (A^T)^Tx = b$$
We can do $QR$ decomposition on $A^T$ to get a square matrix $Q$ which is $n \times n$ and matrix $R$ which is $n \times m$. 
Now we have
$$ (QR)^Tx=b $$
It seems to me that in order to to proceed we must take the inverse of $(QR)^T$ -> $(QR)^{-T}$.

Wiki article notes that $R = \begin{bmatrix} R_1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ where $R_1$ is $m \times m$, and later "with some algebra" we can get that

$$\hat{x} = Q\begin{bmatrix} (R_1)^{-T}b \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

I do not understand the algebra involved in getting this solution. It seems to be that we are stuck on getting the inverse of $(QR)^T$. I can see how you can get the inverse of $Q$ and bring it on the other side since it is an orthogonal matrix, and inverse of $R_1$ since it is square, but what are the rules of carrying out these operations on such augmented matricies?

Is it accurate to say that 
$$ (Q\begin{bmatrix} R_1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix})^{-T} = Q\begin{bmatrix} R_1^{-T} \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

This is the only way I can see that this explicit solution is obtained, why does this work? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Least Squares solution with a QR-decomposition can be done with over-determined systems, i.e. $m>n$. Here "Least Squares" denotes a property of $e:=Ax-b$ by minimizing $\|e\|_2$.

You have an underdetermined system of equations, meaning that a lot of solutions $x$ fulfill $Ax=b$, so there is no error to minimize. "Least Squares" in these works usually refers to a property of the solution $x$ having $\|x\|_2$ minimal. 
This is usually obtained by the pseudo-inverse $A^\dagger$ that can (most easily) calculated from the SVD of $A$.

The solution provided in the Wikipedia-article has nothing to do with a least-squares solution. The general idea of solving underdetermined systems is to ignore many columns of $A$ in order to have a square matrix to invert. You can just choose zeros in the respective entries of $x$. But choosing these columns can be hard, as you have $n$ to choose from that all just form an $m$-dimensional space. You can choose very poorly and have vectors that are close to linearly dependent, making your solution numerically unstable. Computing the QR-decomposition gives you an orthogonal (which is nearly always better) basis, giving you the "best" submatrix to choose from.

I can go into more detail, if required.

Comment: Thank you! You set me on the right path, the "some algebra" part seemed to turn out quite a bit more complex. Found a very nice and detailed solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56vogBfKJu0&list=PLh464gFUoJWOmBYla3zbZbc4nv2AXez6X&index=8

Comment: That's why I would just go into more detail, if required. ;)